# Code in C# to check whether 3rd digit from right is 7

Tags: c#, .net

This is my code to check whether the given number third digit from the right is `7` or not. But after accepting the input the program shuts down itself. Please help and tell me what is it that I've done wrong.

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Threading.Tasks;   

namespace ConsoleApp1    
{    
    class Program    
    {    
        static void Main(string[] args)    
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] u = new int[3];

            for (int j=0; j < 3; j++)    
            { 
                u[j] = y % 10;    
                y = y / 10;    
            }   

            if (u[2] == 7)    
            {    
                Console.WriteLine("yuss");
            }   
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Stick a `Console.ReadLine();` at the end so that it pauses and allows you to read the output before closing the window. Then just press enter when you want to close. I don't think this problem is related to your logic, unless it's throwing an exception somewhere.

Comment: Please read about "How to ask a question" before you ask a question. Your formatting is all over the place.

Comment: @ADyson I did try that ...it's still not happening...! :(

Comment: (Math.Floor(myNumber / 100) % 10) == 7?

Comment: @DigaantGarg where did you put the line? At the end of  the "main" method, I hope, outside any other blocks? It should pause, even if it never goes into your `if` statement to actually produce any output. If it's closing even before that, then maybe there's an exception - have you run it using a debugger and stepped through the code?

Comment: @ADyson I haven't run it using a debugger yet I'll try that, and I put at the end of the main method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
String number = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

if ((number.Length >= 3) && (number[number.Length - 3] == '7'))
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
else
    Console.WriteLine("No");
```

Don't convert user input to `Int32`... things are simpler if you perform your check using a `String`.

Comment: I suggest adding `Trim()` in order to deal with `" 1234     "` inputs: `String number = Console.ReadLine().Trim();`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! :O Didn't think about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TommasoBelluzzo :)

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to check `int`, not `string`:

```
 int y = ...

 if (Math.Abs((y / 100) % 10) == 7) {
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Besides the parsing answers, if you want your program to continue getting input, you can consider a while loop:

```
while(true) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");    
   int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());    
   int[] u = new int[3];    
   for(int j=0;j<3;j++)    
   { 
       u[j] = y % 10;    
       y = y / 10;    
   }    
   if(u[2]==7)    
   {    
       Console.WriteLine("yuss");
   }    
}
```

You can even add a condition, like -1 exits the program (ie breaks the loop):

```
int y = 0;

while(y != -1) {
   y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());    
   int[] u = new int[3];    
   for(int j=0;j<3;j++)    
   { 
       u[j] = y % 10;    
       y = y / 10;    
   }    
   if(u[2]==7)    
   {    
       Console.WriteLine("yuss");
   }    
}
```